# How to count number of times the selectInput box is clicked?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

The below MWE code uses `observeEvent()` functions and `reactiveVal()` to track and show the number of times the `selectInput()` box is clicked and the number of times the `actionButton()` is clicked.

The `actionButton()` tracking works fine. Note how in `output$...` in the code the `selectInput()` and `actionButton()` work differently, looks weird to me.

Anyhow, I'm having trouble having `selectInput()` track the same as `actionButton()`. When the App is first invoked, the user clicking the first option rendered ("Cyl") in the `selectInput()` box is not counted as a click, when I would like it to count as a click. And if the same choice is clicked in the `selectInput()` ("Trans" for example) more than once, the clicks > 1 aren't counted as clicks when I would each click to be counted. Basically, anytime the user clicks in the `selectInput()` box it needs to be included as a "click". Is there any way to do this?

In the full code this matters because the `selectInput()` in that box triggers a `removeUI()` and the list of choices is dynamic and sequentially renumbered with every click.

Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(hr(),
  selectInput("selInput",label=NULL,c("Cyl"="cyl","Trans"="am","Gears"="gear"),selected=NULL),
  actionButton("addBtn","Add"), hr(),
  textOutput("clickSelInput"),
  textOutput("clickAddBtn"),
  tableOutput("data")
)
  
server = function(input, output) {
  x = reactiveVal(0)
  y = reactiveVal(0)
    
  output$data <- renderTable({mtcars[1:10, c("mpg", input$selInput), drop = FALSE]})
    
  observeEvent(input$selInput,{x(x()+1)})
  observeEvent(input$addBtn,{y(y()+1)})
    
  output$clickSelInput <- renderText({paste('Select Input clicks =',x()-1)})
  output$clickAddBtn <- renderText({paste('Add Button clicks =',y())})
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is 1 subtracted from `x()` and not subtracted from `y()` on purpose?

Comment: That was the only way I could get it to work! When you go to `selectInput` and click anything other than the first rendered choice (when first running the App), and don't click the same choice twice or more, then it correctly adds up the number of times `selectInput` was accessed. The `actionButton()` on the other hand works completely fine.

Comment: I do not think there is a "shiny" way of doing this. The `selectInput` behaves like it should. But I would bet that it can be done by adding a little javascript. Maybe you could add it to the tags to attract the right people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "multiple = TRUE" to the `selectInput()` in this case resolves the question. Also allow the removal of the weird -1 from the `out$selInput..x()-1)})` in the OP. This also works fine for the larger App this is intended for. See revised OP code with changes from OP commented (further down is the "larger App" where this functionality matters):

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(hr(),
  selectInput("selInput",
              label=NULL,
              c("Cyl"="cyl","Trans"="am","Gears"="gear"),
              selected=NULL,
              multiple=TRUE # added this
              ),
  actionButton("addBtn","Add"), hr(),
  textOutput("clickSelInput"),
  textOutput("clickAddBtn"),
  tableOutput("data")
)
  
server = function(input, output) {
  x = reactiveVal(0)
  y = reactiveVal(0)
    
  output$data <- renderTable({mtcars[1:10, c("mpg", input$selInput), drop = FALSE]})
    
  observeEvent(input$selInput,{x(x()+1)})
  observeEvent(input$addBtn,{y(y()+1)})
    
  output$clickSelInput <- renderText({paste('Select Input clicks =',x())}) # removed the -1 from x()
  output$clickAddBtn <- renderText({paste('Add Button clicks =',y())})
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And here's the "larger App" where this functionality matters:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

rowNames1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "Sum")
DF1 <- data.frame(row.names = rowNames1, "Col 1" = c(1, 1, 0, 2), check.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(br(),
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable1'),br(),
  actionButton("addCol1", "Add column 1"),br(),
  h5(strong("Select column to delete:")),
  uiOutput("delCol1"), hr(),
  textOutput("clickSelInput"),
  textOutput("clickAddBtn"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  x = reactiveVal(0)
  y = reactiveVal(0)
  uiTbl1 <- reactiveVal(DF1)
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable1, {uiTbl1(hot_to_r(input$hottable1))})
  
  output$hottable1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTbl1(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)%>%
      hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addCol1, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,2))
    names(newCol) <- paste("Col", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable1)) + 1)
    uiTbl1(cbind(uiTbl1(), newCol))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$delCol1, {
    tmp <- uiTbl1()                  
    delCol <- input$delCol1                              
    tmp <- tmp[ , !(names(tmp) %in% delCol), drop = FALSE]  
    newNames <- sprintf("Col %d",seq(1:ncol(tmp)))       
    names(tmp) <- newNames                                  
    uiTbl1(tmp)                                         
  })

  output$delCol1 <- 
    renderUI(
      selectInput(
        "delCol1", 
        label = NULL,
        choices = colnames(hot_to_r(input$hottable1)), 
        selected = "",
        multiple = TRUE)
      )

  observeEvent(input$delCol1,{x(x()+1)})
  observeEvent(input$addCol1,{y(y()+1)})
  
  output$clickSelInput <- renderText({paste('Select Input clicks =',x())})
  output$clickAddBtn <- renderText({paste('Add Button clicks =',y())})
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```